# Why doesn't this TypeScript constant satisfy this interface?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement a function that complies with an interface having both a call signature and a constructor signature. I've seen this is possible in the type declarations here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L142

I would like to be able to implement something like that myself. Below is my attempt.

```
class C {
    public x: number;
    constructor(x: number) {
        return { x };
    }
}

interface I {
    new(x: number): C;
    (x: number): C;
}

const x: I = C;
```

I think it should work given that we could call `new x(3)` and we would get back a `C` and similarly, we could call `x(3)` and get back a `C`, but there is an error:

`Type 'typeof C' is not assignable to type 'I'. Type 'typeof C' provides no match for the signature '(x: number): C'`

For convenience, I copied the code in a playground snippet accessible [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(x%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20x%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20I%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(x%3A%20number)%3A%20C%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(x%3A%20number)%3A%20C%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20I%20%3D%20C%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(x(3))%3B).

Comment: check it here http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(x%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20I%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new(x%3A%20number)%3A%20C%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20init%3F(x%3A%20number)%3A%20C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20I%20%3D%20C%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20x(3)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test.x)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A

Comment: @Niladri if I were to guess that works because it's the same as if the init field weren't there.

Comment: I made that function optional because your Class C does not have a definition for that function, if you don't make it optional then it will look for that function also in `x`

Comment: But the definition class C (when transpiled to ES5) satisfies the definitions of both the functions there. You can check the answer to see why it doesn't pass the type checking process :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's expected that `I` can be called as regular function, while ES6 classes can be called only with `new`.

Even though `C` can be called like `C(1)` *with E5 target* because it's transpiled to regular function (although explicit `{ x }` return that doesn't use `this` is antipattern), ES6 classes cannot.

Interfaces like `ObjectConstructor` (which designates `Object` built-in) that allow calls both with and without `new` with same result exist for historical reasons. Besides that this approach isn't applicable to ES6 classes, it isn't considered a good practice in general if a function cannot benefit from `new` call.

In order to match `I` type, `C` should be asserted to it, because classes and void functions are de jure `new`able in TypeScript, and functions that return values are not:

```
interface C {
    x: number;    
}
const C = <{ new(x: number): C, (x: number): C }><any>function (x: number): C {
  return { x };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am mostly curious if it would be possible to create a function that would pass the TypeScript type checking process that implements that interface. I got why it can't be done with classes.

Do you know how/if any function could satisfy that interface? Thanks!

Comment: I understand that semantically, a function that does not explicitly use `this` can fulfil both the constructor role and that of an object with a call signature, but as far as I can tell, it won't pass the TypeScript type checking.

Comment: As for type checking, I updated the question. As you can see, you have to fight TS at this point.